# Who died in A Song of Ice And Fire?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

So recently, an image macro has been making the rounds, where J.K. Rowling mentions how hard it is to kill off so many characters, with G.R.R. Martin beneath that saying "You're adorable". Besides them, there is an image of a stack of books with a tab for each person that gets killed.

[image]

From what I can tell, the entire Harry Potter series appears to have less deaths than 1 book from the ASOIAF series. But how many death does each series have, exactly? This question will handle ASOIAF, I created another question already for Harry Potter.

Just the main book series and only named deaths please. I'm not interested in movie/TV show or spin-off deaths.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this question received 2 downvotes, while the Harry Potter question received 1 upvote and no downvotes?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107687/how-many-people-actually-died-during-the-war-of-the-five-kings

Comment: I don't know, but I can think of many: In ASOIAF the number of deaths is a few orders of magnitude higher and it has been discussed time and time again, while in HP everything is quite straight forward and  not so outstanding. Also, you are very wrong in your assessment of what is circulated recently, you are even pulling the worst "quote" conceivable. I wrote my answer after I confirmed everything with about 2 minutes of googling, so it would appear you haven't put that much effort into trying to find answers yourself. The comment you got on the HP question tells the tale ...

Comment: @user1129682 I had personally deleted the questions because I thought they were a poor fit myself. However, I got comments on another question asking me to revive them. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102669/why-did-leia-give-the-stolen-version-of-the-death-star-plans-to-r2-d2-instead-of?noredirect=1#comment325033_102669

Comment: Isn't [This Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128936/who-died-in-harry-potter) and the one we are on same? Why create two posts for same question?

Comment: @NSNoob This one is for the books written by G.R.R. Martin, the other one is for the books written by J.K. Rowling. They're separate series, so I made separate questions.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128936/4918 "Who died in Harry Potter?"

Answer (score 2):

Well, the actual Twitters that were the basis for this picture are two years old and the correct quote from Twitter was "Oh my sweet summer child", [see here](https://twitter.com/georgerrmartin_/status/462440220122558464). I only did a sloppy image search, but the image of the stack of books with all the deaths marked is at least from Nov. 2013, maybe earlier.

[Here](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/47887-list-of-death/) is an initial death list.

I suppose you could go through the [list of characters on A Wiki Of Ice And Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/List_of_characters) to complete it.

Comment: Must give +1 for the twitter link. Best meme ever. :D

Comment: I might add that that's not the real GRRM's twitter account. His real account is [@GRRMSpeaking](https://twitter.com/GRRMspeaking)